# Reading a file and adding 10 array elements at the beginning of each line read to the array i'm storing the file's lines

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have a file which I'm reading, and storing the char's individually from the file in to an array.
My question is: While reading the file, how can I insert a 10 elements to the array before reading a new line.

**Example:**

> File:
>
> 471 22 01 05 34 75 78 65 46 34 20 19
>
> 521 01 02 03 45 35 42 36 87 99 12 23 12 37 64

**When I read the file it should end up like this:**

> [V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,22,01,05,34,75,78,65,46,34,20,19,V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,01,02,03,45,35,42,36,87,99,12,23,12,37,64]

***My current idea is:***

Before starting to read the file, I have already inserted the 10 first elements in the array. Then while reading the file, whenever I find a '\0', using a loop I would insert the variables again, this is what I got:

```
        Elements = [V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9];//array of elements to insert

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        //this loop reads the file and ignores what's not necessary(it's working properly)

        while(s2[i] != '\0')//reading chars from the file
        {
            if(s2[i] == ' ')
                i++;

            MEM[j]=atoi((s2+i));//MEM is the array in which i'm storing the lines

            i += 3;//increment by 3 due to problem specifics(needs to ignore the first 3 values from the file)
            j++;
        }
```

I know my idea is not very effective but I'm new to C and I don't know how to properly do this.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to copy the contents of a text file to a buffer (or char array) and insert an specific amount of characters at the beginning of each line?

Comment: @wxShayan no, not in to file. Specifically in to the array, i'll be using the array as I gave the example later on

Answer (score 1):

As you shown input file contains

```
471 22 01 05 34 75 78 65 46 34 20 19
521 01 02 03 45 35 42 36 87 99 12 23 12 37 64
```

Instead of reading *char by char*, you can read *word by word* using `fscanf()` since shown file consist of similar types(all are numbers). From the manual page of `fscanf()`.

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

Read one-one integer and allocate dynamic memory everytime by calling `realloc()`, in this case you no need to worry about size of array. Here is the sample code to read data from file and store into integer array.

```
int main(void) {
        FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
        if(fp == NULL){
                /*.. error handling */
                return 0;
        }
        int row = 1;
        int *input = malloc(sizeof(*input));/*1st time 4 byte, to store first integer inside file */
        /*  here input is dynamic array */
        while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&input[row-1]) == 1) { /* fscanf() read upto whitespace at a time */
                row++;
                input = realloc(input,row * sizeof(*input));/* reallocate based on number of input */
        }
        for(int index = 0 ; index < row-1 ;index++) {
                printf("%d\n",input[index]);
        }
        /* free dynamically allocated memory @TODO*/
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You actually helped me with the reading part, but I still have the hardest part to work out, the variable insertion in the array, do you have any ideas?

Comment: That too I explained. `fscanf()` read one integer from file and store into `input[0]` which is nothing but one element of array. Here `int *input = malloc()` is dynamic 1D array. Is this you want or something else ?

Comment: something else sorry, the elements i want to add to the array are not in the file. The array needs to have reserved space for those 10 elements. Check my example, the elements are added to the array but are not in the file